# Adjust node location automatically with coordinate transformation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to adjust the location of a node on a path automatically when there is a coordinate transformation on the path. In the example below, I cheated and manually adjusted the location of the nodes.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \rotationangle {120};

%Line without a rotation
\begin{scope}[rotate=0];
   \draw(0,0) -- (5cm,0)
   node[at start, left]{a}
   node[at end, right]{b}
   node[midway, above]{\tiny a) Unrotated};
\end{scope}

%Line with a rotation, but nodes are not aligned with line axis
\begin{scope}[yshift=1cm, rotate=\rotationangle];
   \draw(0,0) -- (5cm,0)
   node[at start, left]{a}
   node[at end, right]{b}
   node[midway]{\tiny b)Rotated, but nodes are not aligned};
\end{scope}

%Line with rotation, nodes are aligned with line axis with a cheat.
%Can the nodes be aligned with w.r.t. the rotation automatically. 
\begin{scope}[yshift=1cm, , xshift=5cm,  rotate=\rotationangle];
   \draw(0,0) -- (5cm,0)
   node[at start, xshift=0.15cm, yshift=-0.2cm]{a}   %Cheated with xshift and yshift
   node[at end, xshift=-0.35cm, yshift=0.25cm, anchor=west]{b} %Cheated with xshift and yshift
   node[midway]{\tiny c)Rotated, nodes are aligned, but cheated};   
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

I can write a code to make the adjustment with for example, tikzmath, and make it automated. However, I wonder if there is a built-in-Tikz way of doing this.

Comment: You could perhaps do `\draw node (a) at (0,0) {a} node (b) at (5cm,0) {b}  (a) -- (b) node[midway]{\tiny b)Rotated, nodes are aligned};`, but the result is not the same as in your code.

Comment: @TorbjørnT Is there a way to apply your solution while keeping the line length 5cm?

Comment: No, but I thought of a simpler solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just set an appropriate `anchor` for the two nodes, based on the `\rotationangle`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \rotationangle {120};

\begin{scope}[rotate=\rotationangle];
   \draw (0,0) -- (5cm,0)
   node[circle,anchor=\rotationangle,pos=0] {a}
   node[circle,anchor=\rotationangle+180,pos=1] {b}
   node[midway]{\tiny b)Rotated, nodes are aligned};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Load the `calc` library and position nodes `a` and `b` along the direction `(0,0) -- (5cm,0)`, or the reverse direction, with a fixed offset of your choice (`1em` below). The syntax is like this: `($(point1) ! distance from point1 along the direction point1 -- point2 ! (point2)$)`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \rotationangle {120};

%Line without a rotation
\begin{scope}[rotate=0];
   \draw(0,0) -- (5cm,0)
   node[at start, left]{a}
   node[at end, right]{b}
   node[midway, above]{\tiny a) Unrotated};
\end{scope}

%Line with a rotation, but nodes are not aligned with line axis
\begin{scope}[yshift=1cm, rotate=\rotationangle];
   \draw(0,0)coordinate(1) -- (5cm,0)coordinate(2)
   node at ($(1)!-1em!(2)$) {a}
   node at ($(2)!-1em!(1)$) {b}
   node[midway]{\tiny b)Rotated, and nodes are aligned};
\end{scope}

%Line with rotation, nodes are aligned with line axis with a cheat.
%Can the nodes be aligned with w.r.t. the rotation automatically. 
\begin{scope}[yshift=1cm, , xshift=5cm,  rotate=\rotationangle];
   \draw(0,0) -- (5cm,0)
   node[at start, xshift=0.15cm, yshift=-0.2cm]{a}   %Cheated with xshift and yshift
   node[at end, xshift=-0.35cm, yshift=0.25cm, anchor=west]{b} %Cheated with xshift and yshift
   node[midway]{\tiny c)Rotated, nodes are aligned, but cheated};   
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An example where the solution provided by Torbjørn T. can be used:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \rotationangle {168};
\begin{scope}[rotate=\rotationangle];
   \draw (0,0)  node[circle,anchor=\rotationangle+45]{a}
   -- ++(5cm,0) node[circle,anchor=\rotationangle+135]{b}
   -- ++(0,5cm) node[circle,anchor=\rotationangle+225]{c}
   -- ++(-5,0)  node[circle,anchor=\rotationangle+315]{d}
   -- cycle;
   \node at (2.5,2.5) {Angle = \rotationangle degrees};
   \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]